# Arranging the column values in R based on similar pairs present in data

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

The script below is a data frame of three columns. My need is that I want to take a pair of values(a1,a2) at a time. If there is a duplicate of the pair present in the table, then I want to arrange the corresponding a3 values in asecending order. For illustration, first (a1,a2) value pair is ("A","D"), we see that they occur again at 4th and 7th position. So, I want the pair to be compared with every row here and after finding the 4th and 7th, get the corresponding "a3" values arranged in ascending order, similarly for all the row pairs. Kindly try avoiding loops and if's as it may slow down the process. I tried using "arrange", but no help. Thanks and please suggest.

```
a1 = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A")
a2 = c("D","E","F","D","F","E","D")
a3 = c(20,40,50,5,15,35,10)
a123= data.frame(a1,a2,a3)
View(a123)
```

**Expected Outcome**

```
a1 = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A")
a2 = c("D","E","F","D","F","E","D")
a3 = c(5,40,50,10,15,35,20)
a123 = data.frame(a1,a2,a3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can group the data by `a1` and `a2`, and then use `mutate` and `sort` to rearrange the numbers in `a3`. `a123_r` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

a123_r <- a123 %>%
  group_by(a1, a2) %>%
  mutate(a3 = sort(a3)) %>%
  ungroup()
a123_r

# # A tibble: 7 x 3
#   a1     a2       a3
#   <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>
# 1 A      D      5.00
# 2 B      E      40.0 
# 3 C      F      50.0 
# 4 A      D      10.0 
# 5 B      F      15.0 
# 6 C      E      35.0 
# 7 A      D      20.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir for your effort, fits perfectly, however as I am working on my problem, I have come across an extra column in the data to be filtered in which I need assistance, should I add in the requirement above?

Comment: Please ask a new question as this question is completed.

Comment: Sure as you suggested, I have created a new question with addon requirement, would appreciate your assistance on the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48023937/sorting-the-values-of-column-in-ascending-order-in-r

Answer (score 0):

i would just paste them to another column to create a key.

```
a4 = paste(a1,a2)
a123 = cbind(a123,a4)
a123[order(a123$a4,a123$a3),]
#  a1 a2 a3  a4
#4  A  D  5 A D
#7  A  D 10 A D
#1  A  D 20 A D
#2  B  E 40 B E
#5  B  F 15 B F
#6  C  E 35 C E
#3  C  F 50 C F
# or save the new order
a123 = a123[order(a123$a4,a123$a3),]
```

Comment: thank you so much Dror for replying, as per my need, I have requested for the column a3 values to change in ascending order only for those pairs in a1 and a2 which have duplicates present in the data, there should not be any change done to a1, a2 columns. Kindly suggest.

Comment: kindly check for the output that I have put in the question above, it might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table` solution which updates only column `a3` by reference, i.e., without copying the whole data object `a123`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a123)[, a3 := sort(a3), by = .(a1, a2)][]
```

> ```
>    a1 a2 a3
> 1:  A  D  5
> 2:  B  E 40
> 3:  C  F 50
> 4:  A  D 10
> 5:  B  F 15
> 6:  C  E 35
> 7:  A  D 20
> ```